# MetaPost & gmp package. How to use diacritical signs inside mpost?

Tags: metapost

First of all, I've read this question:
[Proper use of the emp package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194176/proper-use-of-the-emp-package).

But...

How to use diacritical signs inside mpost? Like ā, ä, ā, ä, ǟ, ḑ, ē, ī...

The project was created on overleaf.com.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\gmpoptions{everymp={input expressg;}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{mpost}
z0 = origin;
drawroundedbox(0, 2.5cm, 3cm, 5mm)(
  \btex {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} ā, ä, ā, ä, ǟ, ḑ, ē, ī... \end{tabular}} etex
);
\end{mpost}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It produces nothing.

I was using this [site](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/) to test the MetaPost.

Comment: Can you please give us a complete example rather than just fragments of code? It will be much easier for people to help you. Could you also clarify what you are trying to do? What do you mean by `national character`? `$\alpha$` is a mathematical symbol. If you wanted to typeset Greek, you wouldn't do it this way. And `\alpha` doesn't seem to have much to do with typesetting letters with a diaeresis. Is the point that you want to input these as unicode characters? Or...?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question is more specified now. I was using this site to test MetaPost: http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/ I just wanted to know how to write diacritical signs like õ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your choice of packages, the simple

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

ā, ä, ā, ä, ǟ, ḑ, ē, ī

\end{document}
```

would raise the same errors, since `ā ǟ ḑ ē ī` are not supported by the `utf8` option, even if `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is loaded. So it's no surprise they don't work in an `mpost` environment. On the other hand

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}

\gmpoptions{everymp={input expressg;}}
\usempxpackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usempxpackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{mpost}
z0 = origin;
drawroundedbox(0, 2.5cm, 3cm, 5mm)(
  \btex {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} ä, ă, ö \end{tabular}} etex
);
\end{mpost}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

works flawlessly, producing

[image]

This works, by teaching LaTeX how it should deal with the unknown characters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}

\gmpoptions{everymp={input expressg;}}
\usempxpackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usempxpackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usempxpackage{newunicodechar}
\mpxcommands{%
  \newunicodechar{ā}{\=a}%
  \newunicodechar{ē}{\=e}%
  \newunicodechar{ī}{\={\i}}%
  \newunicodechar{ḑ}{\d{d}}%
  \newunicodechar{ǟ}{\={ä}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{mpost}
z0 = origin;
drawroundedbox(0, 2.5cm, 3cm, 5mm)(
  \btex {\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} ā, ä, ā, ä, ǟ, ḑ, ē, ī \end{tabular}} etex
);
\end{mpost}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the same declarations should be made for the main document, if you want those characters also in normal text.